# Grey badges for Meta SO theme?

Tags: discussion

Are there going to be alternate colored badges for this distinctly grey site?

Comment: lol. great question. the whole grey-scale thing is pretty depressing.

Comment: At least the overflowing stack in the logo could be as red as 'meta'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"All badges should be silver on meta-SO. :)" -- Bill the Lizard

No, the badges should be tin, silver, and platinum.

Comment: I was really hoping for carbon steel, galvanized steel, and stainless steel.  Wouldn't want to excite the masses too much.

Answer (score 3):

All badges should be silver on meta-SO. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Badges](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqomZQMZQCQ)? We don't need no stinkin' [badges](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3H7l3RZEik)!

Comment: You mispelled that one...should be badgers....